# Distribution limit with $O(1)$ term

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

Let's say we have a sequence of random variables $X_n$ where $V = \text{var}(X_n)$. Suppose that (this is convergence in distribution)

$$V^{-1/2}(X_n - E(X_n)) \leadsto N(0,1)$$

I'm wondering, is it true that $$V^{-1/2}(O(1)X_n - E(X_n)) \leadsto N(0,1)??$$

Thanks

**Edit**: I realized this shouldn't hold for every $O(1)$. Instead, let's replace $O(1)$ for a nonstochastic sequence $a_n \rightarrow 1$. I think a simple proof could follow by Slutsky theorem: If $X_n \leadsto N(0,1)$ and $X_n - Y_n$ converges to $0$ in probability, then $Y_n \leadsto N(0,1)$.

So, if $V^{-1/2}(X_n - E(X_n)) - V^{-1/2}(a_nX_n - E(X_n))$ converges to $0$ in probability, that's it. But
$$V^{-1/2}(X_n - E(X_n)) - V^{-1/2}(a_nX_n - E(X_n)) = V^{-1/2}(X_n - a_n X_n).$$ Is it true that $(X_n - a_n X_n)$ converges to $0$ almost surely? (I think is easier to check that instead of convergence in probability). Specifically, is it true that

$$P \Big(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (X_n - a_n X_n)=0 \Big) = P \Big(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_n - \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} X_n=0 \Big)?$$

Comment: I think this is true if the $O(1)$ term converges to $1$ itself, but if it is just a constant like $2$, why would you expect the limit to hold?

Comment: @AlexOrtiz Thanks, I realized of that a little bit later. Check my edit on the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, in this case it isn't too bad to show that the sequence you are interested in converges to $0$ in probability using Chebyshev's inequality. Assuming $a_n\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}1$,
\begin{align*}
P(V_n^{-1/2}(X_n-a_nX_n)\ge \varepsilon) &= P\big((1-a_n)X_n\ge \varepsilon\sqrt{E(X_n^2)}\big)\\
&\text{Apply Markov $P(Z\ge 1)\le E|Z|$ with $Z = \frac{(1-a_n)^2X_n^2}{\varepsilon^2E(X_n^2)}$}\\
&\le \frac{1}{\varepsilon^2E(X_n^2)}(1-a_n)^2E(X_n^2) = \varepsilon^{-2}(1-a_n^2)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0.
\end{align*}
By Slutsky's theorem (also called "the converging together lemma"), $$V_n^{-1/2}(a_nX_n-E(X_n))\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\leadsto} N(0,1).$$

---

Added: If $|X_n|<\infty$ a.s. are arbitrary random variables and $b_n$ is a sequence converging to $0$ *sufficiently fast,* then we will have $b_nX_n\to 0$ a.s. To see this, pick $b_n > 0$ so that $P(b_n|X_n| > 1/n) < 2^{-n}$. Then $\sum P(b_n|X_n|>1/n) < \infty$, and by Borel-Cantelli, $b_nX_n\to 0$ a.s.

This leads me to believe that if all we assume about the sequence $a_n$ is that $a_n\to 1$, then we can't conclude in general that $(a_n-1)X_n\to 0$ a.s. This is clearly equivalent to asking whether if $b_n\to 0$ we have $b_nX_n\to 0$ a.s.

Comment: Thank you so much, I forgot about Chebyshev's inequality. Just for the sake of it :), can you reply the question in my edit? I mean is it true the almost sure convergence that I state?

Comment: I think I didn't quite follow the inequality, the expression shouldn't be of the form $|X_n - E(X_n)|$ in order to apply Chebyshev?

Comment: @Ejrionm: In your edit, could you clarify the equality of probabilities you wrote? In the left-hand side you haven't said what the limit should be equal to... Presumably 0. Also, by "Chebyshev's inequality" I mean what analysts usually call Chebyshev's inequality, which is what I assume probabilists call "Markov's inequality" after you square what's inside the probability. I can add more details if necessary.

Comment: You're right, I forgot the $=0$ inside the probabilities. Indeed, I'd like that probability to be $1$ in order to conclude the almost sure convergence.

Comment: If you can add the details, it would be great. But I think I get the idea, you can state that $X_n \geq \varepsilon \sqrt{E(X_n^2)} (1-a_n)^{-1}$ and then $X_n^2 \geq \varepsilon^2 E(X_n^2) (1-a_n)^{-2}$ and now apply Markov's inequality, which requires only the positivity of the random variable inside the probability, without the expected value of $X_n$

Comment: Oh, but the probabilities aren't the same, right?

Comment: @Ejrionm: I added the Markov details, and also something about the a.s. convergence question. I think it should be possible to construct a counterexample where $b_nX_n\to 0$ in law, but not almost surely. I haven't found a counterexample yet, however.

Comment: I understand your example. I can't think a counterextample of the fact that $b_n X_n \rightarrow 0$ a.s. if $b_n \rightarrow 0$. But in your edit you found a "sufficient" condition for that to hold. Can we give an explicit form of that *sufficiently fast* condition?